# Can Top clause be used in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Can I use the Top clause in the MYSQL instead of the Limit clause?

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customers;
```

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database, it is a tool to access your database. Remember, MySQL is your database.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're wondering if something is supported, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) can usually explain.

In this case `TOP` is not supported by the MySQL dialect. The MySQL way of expressing that is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers LIMIT 3;
```

There is no simple alternative to the `LIMIT` clause.